# Use Pseudo Variables in Cloudwatch Dashboard Template (Cloudformation)

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to set up a Cloud Formation Template to create a Cloudwatch-Dashboard.
In this context I  want to use the Pseudo Variable to ascertain the Region.

If I simply use the Pseudo Variable `AWS::Region`the code doesnt seem to work:

```
AutoscalingDashboard:
Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
Properties:
  DashboardName: AutoscalingDashboard
  DashboardBody: '
     {
      "widgets":[
        {
            "type":"metric",
            "x":0,
            "y":0,
            "width":12,
            "height":6,
            "properties":{
                "metrics":[
                    [ "AWS/ECS", "MemoryUtilization", "ServiceName", "invoice_web", "ClusterName", "InvoicegenappCluster" ],
                    [ "...", "invoice_data", ".", "." ],
                    [ "...", "invoice_generator", ".", "." ]
                ],
                "region": "AWS::Region",
                "period": 300,
                "view": "timeSeries",
                "title":"ECS MemoryUtilization",
                "stacked": false
            }
```

How can I use the Pseudo Variable `AWS::Region` or a `Ref`Function to keep the variables dynamically?

Merci A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the `DashboardBody` is a string, therefore `AWS::Region` will not get replaced.
You'll probably be better by adding the [`Fn::Sub`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) function, like:

```yaml
AutoscalingDashboard:
  Type: 'AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard'
  Properties:
    DashboardName: 'AutoscalingDashboard'
    DashboardBody: !Sub >-
     {
      "widgets":[
         {
            "type":"metric",
            "x":0,
            "y":0,
            "width":12,
            "height":6,
            "properties":{
                "metrics":[
                    [ "AWS/ECS", "MemoryUtilization", "ServiceName", "invoice_web", "ClusterName", "InvoicegenappCluster" ],
                    [ "...", "invoice_data", ".", "." ],
                    [ "...", "invoice_generator", ".", "." ]
                ],
                "region": "${AWS::Region}",
                "period": 300,
                "view": "timeSeries",
                "title":"ECS MemoryUtilization",
                "stacked": false
            }           
          }]
      }
```

Notice the `${}` around the region, and also the YAML [block string `>-`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/891772).